# When I restart my device, is it possible to connect Bluetooth device without any user interaction, and execute the tasks in background in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios-bluetooth

In my application am using a Bluetooth connection. I got an issue that When I restart my device, is it possible to connect Bluetooth device without any user interaction, and execute the tasks in background.

I have tried with local push notification, but am not getting any control in app. When I clicked on that particular notification only I can able to handle.But that one is not enough.

Kindly please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you implemented Core Bluetooth state restoration?

Comment: @Paulw11 Nope.Let me check and update you.Thanks.

Comment: @SunishaSindhu IIRC, it has something to do with the iPhone/iPad keeping track of the devices it has connected to